# Localization on Eloquent Query with 3 Tables and joins

Tags: laravel, eloquent, localization

I have this method in a model:

```
private function tracks()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Tracker::class,
        FeelingUser::class,
        'user_id', // Foreign key on the FeelUser table
        'feel_user_id', // Foreign key on the Tracker table
        'id', // Local key on the User table
        'id' // Local key on the FeelUser table
    )
        ->join('feelings', 'feel_user.feeling_id', '=', 'feelings.id')
        ->select(
            'trackers.id',
            'feel_user.color',
            'trackers.date',
            'trackers.time',
            'trackers.duration',
            'trackers.comment',
            'feelings.sentiment',
            'feelings.category',
            'feel_user.active',
            'trackers.remember_at',
            'trackers.intensity'
        );
}
```

and I need to add two additional columns that translate to the current local for the colums "feelings.sentiment" and "feelings.category" (i.e.: __($feelings.sentiment)). The method is later used in several other parts, by adding other Eloquent Methods (Orders, Where), plus a get(), or first().

Is there anyway to solve this?

I was thinking of adding local columns in the feeling table, like sentimentDE, and then fetch the column per code, but I dont like the solution, since it could break the query and the API would return 500.

Thx for the advice.

Comment: "but I dont like the solution, since it could break the query" - how?

Comment: I ended up doing the semtiment_DE solution, but made sure all Controllers and Models would only return a language that would exist. So in case somebody would ask for _it, the query would not try to return sentiment_it (which doesn't exist, hence 500 ERR). The solution to control everything from one place, was to put a array in app.php. In my code design, sadly, there are still two places I would need to check, every time I add a new language. 

At some point I need to fix that.